# Resolving error 500; "Cannot access 'object' before initialization" }

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, foreach, reduce

Looking for help on how to resolve this error. I am trying to get an array of monthly transaction summation based on the summation of transactions occurring within each month.

here is my code below,

```js
exports.monthlyTotalArray = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.body;
  const requestMonths = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
  const today = new Date();
  var relevantYear = today.getYear();

  try {
    return await Transaction.findAll({
      where: {
        userId: userId,
      },
    }).then((transactions) => {
      if (transactions.length == 0) {
        res.status(401).json({
          message: { msgBody: "No transactions found", msgError: true },
        });
      } else {
        const MonthlyArray = requestMonths.forEach((requestMonth) => {
          transactions
            .filter((i) => {
              const date = new Date(i.date);
              return (
                date.getMonth() == requestMonth &&
                date.getYear() == relevantYear
              );
            })
            .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + parseFloat(curr.amount), 0);
          res.status(200).send({
            MonthlyArray,
          });
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: error.message || "some error occurred",
    });
  }
};
```

And I get this error when I try to run the code

```
{
  "message": "Cannot access 'MonthlyArray' before initialization"
}
```

Comment: You need to call `res.status(200)...send({ MonthlyArray })` outside of the callback function for `forEach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you're calling `res.send({ MonthlyArray })` inside of the callback function for `requestMonths.forEach`, so that's why you're getting the error.

```js
const MonthlyArray = requestMonths.forEach((requestMonth) => {
  // you're calling it here
  res.status(200).send({
    MonthlyArray,
  });
});
// instead, it should be here
res.status(200).send({
  MonthlyArray,
});
```

Also, you probably don't want to use `forEach` because `forEach` doesn't return anything, so `MonthlyArray` will be `undefined`. Instead, use `Array.map` to get the result you need.

```js
if (transactions.length == 0) {
  // ...
} else {
  const MonthlyArray = requestMonths.map((requestMonth) => {
    return transactions
      .filter((i) => {
        const date = new Date(i.date);
        return (
          date.getMonth() == requestMonth && date.getYear() == relevantYear
        );
      })
      .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + parseFloat(curr.amount), 0);
  });
  res.status(200).send({
    MonthlyArray,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are accessing MonthlyArray in the foreach() lambda expression. But MonthlyArray is actually initialized by the result of that foreach() so you are indeed accessing MonthlyArray before it gets initialized.

It's probably not what you intended but the part of code where you are sending the response is inside the lambda expression.

It's hard to see because the indentation of your code makes it difficult too understand where is the end of your lambda expression.

A proper indentation of your code would most likely make it obvious.

Comment: Thank you @sboisse